# sliding boxes and caption

Tags: jquery, css

My problem is I mouse over and the image slides up and when I mouse off slide back down. but as i have many images and content boxes so whenever i hover on any box all other content boxes also slides with that.what is the problem with this please help me.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qGvDA/)

My Jquery is referenced in a script file:

```
$("ul.contentnav li a").stop().mouseover(function(e){    
   $(this).siblings().slideDown("slow");
    })      
$("ul.contentnav li a").stop().mouseout(function(e){    
     var description = $(this).next($(".description")); 
     var descriptionImg = $(this).next($(".descriptionImg"));
     $(this).siblings().slideUp("slow"); 
     //description.slideUp("slow");
     //$(this).siblings().slideUp("slow");
    })
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="contentnav">
      <li><a href="#content_aboutPearl"><img src="images/afd.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'><p class='description_content'>ABOUT FASHION DESIGN</p></div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#content_fashiondesign"><img src="images/pearl02.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'><p class='description_content'>FASHION DESIGN</p></div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fd3.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>ADMISSION PROCEDURE </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fd4.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>COURSE OVERVIEW </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/dp.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>DOWNLOAD <br />
            PROSPECTUS </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fd6.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>EVENTS/BLOGS </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/daf.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>DOWNLOAD <br />
            APPLICATION FORM </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fd8.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>STUDENTS PORTFOLIO </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fd9.jpg" width="222" height="161" /></a>
        <div class='description'>
          <p class='description_content'>FACULTY </p>
        </div>
        <div class="descriptionImg"><img src="images/plus.png" width="35" height="35" /></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
ul.contentnav {
    list-style: none; /* this removes the list marker */
}
ul.contentnav li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    width: 222px;
    height: 161px;
}
ul.contentnav li:nth-child(3){
margin-right:0px;
}
ul.contentnav li:nth-child(6){
margin-right:0px;
}
ul.contentnav li:nth-child(9){
margin-right:0px;
}

ul.contentnav a, ul.contentnav a:visited { /* grouping these selectors makes sure that your links retain their button look even after being visited */
    /*padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;*/
    display: block; /* this gives the link block properties causing it to fill the whole LI containing it. This causes the entire area to react to a mouse click. */
    width: 220px;  /*this width makes the entire button clickable for IE6. If you don't need to support IE6, it can be removed. Calculate the proper width by subtracting the padding on this link from the width of your sidebar container. */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #e02f1d;
    height: 161px;
    position:relative;
}
ul.contentnav a:hover, ul.contentnav a:active, ul.contentnav a:focus { /* this changes the background and text color for both mouse and keyboard navigators */

    color: #FFF;

}

div.description{  
    position:absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/  
    bottom:0px; /* position will be on bottom */  
    left:0px;  
    width:220px;
    /* styling bellow */  
    background-color:black;  
    font-family: 'tahoma';  
    font-size:15px;  
    color:white;  
    opacity:0.6; /* transparency */  
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* IE transparency */ 
    display:none;
    /*display:block;*/
}  
p.description_content{  
    padding:10px;  
    margin:0px;
    font-size:13px;
}  

div.descriptionImg{  
    position:absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/  
    top:50px; /* position will be on bottom */  
    left:90px;     
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: please guys help me its urgent

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want.  but try this maybe helpful

```
$("ul.contentnav li a").hover(function(){
   $(this).siblings().slideDown("slow");

 },function(){
   var description = $(this).next($(".description")); 
   var descriptionImg = $(this).next($(".descriptionImg"));
   $(this).siblings().slideUp("slow"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"whenever i hover on any box all other content boxes also slides with that"*

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that in order to move the mouse to a particular box you can't help but move it across one or more other boxes, and the hover effect occurs for all those other boxes too.

If so, you can introduce a timeout so that the hover doesn't occur unless the mouse has been in the box for at least, say, 500ms (or whatever time works for you - experiment). If the mouse moves out of a box in that time cancel the timeout before it runs:

```
var timerId;

$("ul.contentnav li a").mouseover(function(e){
    var a = this;
    //clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(function() {    
       $(a).siblings().slideDown("slow");
    }, 500);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    clearTimeout(timerId);
     var description = $(this).siblings(".description");
     var descriptionImg = $(this).siblings(".descriptionImg");
     $(this).siblings().slideUp("slow");
     //description.slideUp("slow");
     //$(this).siblings().slideUp("slow");
});
```

(Note that it doesn't make sense to use `.stop()` the way you were - you were stopping animation once, before assigning the mouse event handlers, at which point there will never be an animation to stop. Also, `.next()` doesn't do what you seem to think it does - it selects the next element if and only if it matches the supplied selector, it doesn't keep looking further down until it finds a matching one - I think if you change this to use `.siblings("your selector")` you'll get the effect you want.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qGvDA/3/

Comment: thanks a lot it realy work after timeout.
thanks nnnnnn  :) 
ur jst amazing man...